# CodeIgniter 3 jQuery ajax call ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on this ajax request with CodeIgniter 3. What I'm doing is press on checkbox and the event calls the function changVisib(). as you will see in the snippet, everything goes well because alert() is called.

But $.ajax() call is completely ignored. I tried $.post(). but no response.

I have searched the web for similar issues, but mine seems different. That's why I'm obliged to ask.

```js
            function changVisib(elem, picId) {
                if (elem.type === 'checkbox') {
                    var cva = 0;
                    if (elem.checked) {
                        cva = 1;
                    } else {
                        cva = 0;
                    }
                    alert('ok up to here');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo base_url()?>admin/gallery_update",
                        data: {id: picId, shown: cva},
                        dataType: "json"
                    });
                }
            }
```

Other jQuery functions work perfectly well. But the call to ajax, post, get seems not to work.

Comment: Do you get any specific error? Also you need a success function defined

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a success handler so that you know that the ajax request finished

```
        function changVisib(elem, picId) {
            if (elem.type === 'checkbox') {
                var cva = 0;
                if (elem.checked) {
                    cva = 1;
                } else {
                    cva = 0;
                }
                alert('ok up to here');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url()?>admin/gallery_update",
                    data: {id: picId, shown: cva},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data){
                         alert( "success" );
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

data - the return data from the ajax request

Read more about the ajax jquery method here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered where the issue was. **ajax** queries were ignored because I was using the ***slim*** version of **jQuery**.

I have come to learn that ***jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js*** does not include **ajax** and **effects**, according to https://jquery.com/download/.

Comment: Now again, I have this line in my codes, but jQuery.ajax is not working <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>